# Behaviour of withCredentials flag of XMLHttpRequest lvl 2 in browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, cors

i'm trying to set a cookie in a XMLHttpRequest in a CORS environment, i receive the cookie in the last call to my server (developed with Restlet) in the Set-Cookie Header. As i can't read this header i have to leave the control to the browser (Chrome in this case), all the request to the server have to include the same value in the Cookie Header (the receive cookie in the first request). 
I have to put the withCredentials (and set the allow-credentials header in the server) in the xhr request in the first call? this flag will take the Set-Cookie and put in the next xhr request on the Cookie header?

Can someone clarify the behaviour of withCredentials flag in the browser? and other issue, in cors can i access to the document.cookie to set it? (will be the same if i can setRequestHeader("Cookie", value))????

Comment: i have come to the conclusion of i cant use the withCredentials flag, i'm using a digest authentication and my server sends me a cookie to send in the rest of the ajax calls. If i put to true withCredentials the browser uses its own implementation of authenticate (show the login window). I'm going to not use the withCredentials and i go to implement a custom http header to send the cookie and process it with my javascript api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you got into the Preflight request issue. If you add extra headers or use withCredentials browser will first try to make a Preflight request (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0) with OPTIONS HTTP verb. In Preflight credentials are dropped (including cookies) - check in Chrome Network panel if it is the case.